# How to create a moving circle in Android

Tags: android, geometry

Here is my code. I don't know whether it is true or not.
So please let me know what to do with this code to make the circle keep on moving.
If the code is wrong then please make it true in an easier way. 
i am new to android.
Please help!!

```
package com.example.experiment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new GUIs(this));
    }
    public class GUIs extends View implements Runnable
    {
        Thread t=new Thread();
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        public GUIs(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
        }
        public void start()
        {
            t.start();
        }
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000, 1);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.drawCircle(100+i, 100+i, 20, paint);
            i+=10;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is working as far as you know, then [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the SE site for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add invalidate() to the View's onDraw method, this will redraw your view (circle) but I propose to take a look at this [Animations and Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html)

Comment: Thanks man the invalidate() method is working.